# Bankers Algorithm - maximum number of processes

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, synchronization, deadlocks

I recently got the following question in my exam.

**Q1) In the banker's algorithm, if the total number of resources in the system is 20 and the maximum resource allocation for a process is 5, what is the maximum number of processes that can be running simultaneously?**

Options

1. 1
2. 4
3. 5
4. 20

The answer is given as **5**.

I believe it should be **4** because with 5 processes there is still a situation where deadlock could still happen - when all the resouces are equally distributed among all the processes i.e. 20/5 = 4 resources/process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It should be 4 only.

$4\times n+1 \leqslant 20 $

Maximum possible value of n is 4